# not changing element in ListView freezes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a problem with my ListView. The first element of the ListView is a View which does not change. The other elements are created dinamicly in the getView method. The problem is, that the first element freezes sometimes and the progressBar in it doesn't turn anymore. This happens only when i scroll down and then up again to the first element. Any Idea how i can solve that problem?

The Code below is shortened and contains only the relevant parts:

The ListViews Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private View main_control;

public PictureShowAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> URLs){
    super(context, R.layout.picture_show_items, URLs);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    main_control = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
}

public View getView(final int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(position == 0){
        return main_control;
    } else{
        //...create and return other items
    }
}
```

}

The Layout main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:background="#dddddd" >
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">      
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:hint="@string/mainActivity_textView_Hint"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:text="" >
</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickDownload"
    android:text="@string/mainActivity_button" />
```

Comment: If you remove the special handling for first element, does the problem go away?  Also, why you are not using "return this.main_control;"? What is PictureShowActivity and what value does PictureShowActivity.main_control has?  I don't see it getting initialized

Comment: I'm sorry i just shortened it wrong. I edited it to correct it.
What do you mean with special handling?

Comment: Does your `else` block reuse view passed as `arg1` or passes it further to `super.getView`?

Comment: no it always inflates a new view and returns it. I will implement the ViewHolder pattern when the rest is working properly.

Comment: I was going to suggest ViewHolder as well (but didn't want to erode answer).  It is a necessary pattern.

Comment: @user1901241 I did not want to suggest holder pattern in this case. I wanted to know whether `main_control` is not being reused.

Comment: no main_control is not reused. I implemented the ViewHolder pattern and added the first element with addHeaderView(main_control) instead of adding it in the adapter, but the problem is still not solved!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a ListView Header instead of creating modifying the adapter to handle changing this component (since the element you want changed the first element in the list?).

I suspect you have logic in your adapter that is causing some long running operation that is causing your issue.

Bottom line, create your top cell element as a header, instead of doing this with your apapter.

Linky: http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-listactivity-with-a-header-or-footer/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution, but the problem still occurs

Comment: You must have something blocking the UI then.  You have something else wrong that you are not showing.  I am 100% sure this is the correct solution for a way to create a static element at the top of a list.

Comment: But the UI-Thread can't be blocked, because the ListView itself is still scrolling properly. Is there maybe a different Thread for this specific View?